# gawk in Cygwin giving "Access is denied" error

Tags: awk, cygwin, access-denied

I'm trying to run a simple awk command using Cygwin.

I want to run through a file and put each line to a file named the same as the first field, appending lines with the same value in the first field to their relevant file.

I am running this command:

```
gawk -F , '{print>\$1}' ./filename.csv
```

The only output I get from command is: "Access is denied."

```
C:\projects>gawk -F , '{print>\$1}' ./filename.csv  
Access is denied.
```

This is what it looks like in total.

I've looked at the file permissions and allowed everything but I can't seem to get it to work.

Edited with extra info as requested:

```
C:\projects>gawk -F , '{print > \$1}' filename.csv
Access is denied.

C:\projects>$SHELL --version
'$SHELL' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\projects>gawk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.5, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; either version 3 of the License, or
(at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program. If not, see http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

I've tried running from the Cygwin Shell and I get this error now:

```
/cygdrive/c/projects/FileSplit
$ gawk -F , '{print > $1}' ./filename.csv
gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=./filename.csv FNR=1) fatal: expression for `>' redirection has null string value
```

Running it in the Cygwin Shell worked although my first field was blank on some lines so the command I ended up with was:

```
gawk -F , '{if(length($1)==0)print > "empty"; else print > $1}' ./filename.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the backslash:

```
gawk -F , '{print > $1}' ./filename.csv
```

Given what you've now added to your question - you're running gawk from the Windows CMD prompt, not from cygwin. Don't do that, run gawk from a cygwin terminal window instead by executing something like `All Programs -> Cygwin -> Cygwin64 Terminal` to start a cygwin window running a bash shell.

Comment: Hi. Thanks, the problem with that is it doesn't recognise the dollar for some reason. it creates an empty file called $1}'  
  
With the console output of:  
  
C:\projects>gawk -F , '{print > $1}' filename.csv  
gawk: cmd. line:1: {print  filename.csv  
gawk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error  
gawk: cmd. line:1: {print  filename.csv  
gawk: cmd. line:1:                     ^ unexpected newline or end of string

Comment: Hang on. You said you're using cygwin but your prompt looks like a windows prompt, you're talking about a "console" and you're describing problems you simply cannot have when using cygwin or any other UNIX platform. Wild guess - are you calling awk from Windows instead of from Cygwin? I assume `C:\projects>` is your prompt and you're not executing that string, right?

Comment: I am using cygwin with Windows shell integration. Cygwin is a unix environment for Windows.

Comment: I know what Cygwin is, I've used it daily for 10+ years and it does not behave as you described given the posted awk script. If you edit your question to show a copy/paste of the script you're executing and the error you're getting formatted pcorrectly using the editors `{}` button maybe someone will spot something. Also show you executing `$SHELL --version` and `awk --version` and the output you get from both.

Comment: I appreciate the help but telling me I'm not getting the error I am getting when I am clearly getting that error is a bit odd. I've edited the question exactly as you've asked. If you don't know the answer that's fine, thanks for trying.

Comment: I didn't say you're not getting the error you're getting, I said you don't get that error by running that awk script on cygwin and told you how to provide additional information so we could continue helping you debug it. Given what you provided it's clear that you are trying to run gawk from the Windows CMD prompt, NOT from cygwin.

Comment: Cygwin is executing the command it's just integrated with the windows shell.

Comment: Cygwin, as you mentioned, provides a UNIX environment on Windows. Your command will not fail as you describe when run in a UNIX environment. Your command is failing for the reason I said (i.e. you are running it in a Windows environment) and if you do what I suggested to run it in the Cygwin UNIX environment instead it will no longer fail. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I got a different error but it was because the data in field one was empty so I ended up with this:

gawk -F , '{if(length($1)==0)print > "empty"; else print > $1}' ./filename.csv